# Makefile: how to silence implicit rule output

Tags: makefile

I know how to silence a line from a rule with @, I also know how to silence a whole rule with .SILENT, but I don't find the answer of how to silence the output of implicit rules?

Answer (score 0):

You can silence implicit rules using `.SILENT`, just add the targets that match the implicit rules:

```
all: prog
prog: $(OBJS)
        $(LINK)...

.SILENT: $(OBJS)
```

If that doesn't answer your question you'll have to be more explicit: show an example of the makefile, the command you typed, and the output you got, and explain what you expected instead.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, I red in an other topic that .SILENT was out of date and was silencing everything including compilation errors, I just test it and doing the job perfectly, I tried to remove a file and the output told me the file was missing. 
Sorry I should have try it even if I red it was silencing completly the target.